# Cannot create tasks to upload Proguard Mapping File.java.lang.IllegalStateException: Resolving configuration 'androidTestAnnotationProcessor'

Tags: android, firebase, android-proguard

Upgraded to Android Studio 3.0 canary 3 and with it gradle-4.0-milestone-1-all Due to the new way of evaluating dependencies the current plugin used in https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/android#uploading_proguard_mapping_files_with_gradle no longer works, running the task:

```
$ gradlew app:firebaseUploadReleaseProguardMapping
```

Yields an error:

> Cannot create tasks to upload Proguard Mapping
>   File.java.lang.IllegalStateException: Resolving configuration
>   'androidTestAnnotationProcessor' directly is not allowed

Any suggestions to make this work?

Comment: Seeing same issue.....looks like it's known issue and fix is being worked on - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/JqnlnGK2ddY

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Updates from - groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/JqnlnGK2ddY

Change from

```
    classpath('com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.0') {
```

to

```
    classpath('com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.0-alpha1') {
```

Comment: com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.1 does not fix it. The 1.1.0-alpha1 fixes are not carried forward to 1.1.1 :(

Comment: classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5' fixes the issue.

Answer (score 5):

`classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5'` fixes the issue.

Ref: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/android#known_issue

Comment: This is the correct answer. Do check out the referenced link and use the version mentioned there.